# Neo4j Install on ubuntu password not working

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I have neo4j enterprise version installed on ubuntu but the password and user isn't working

[image: but the password and user isn't working]

I tried

- default neo4j password
- neo4j-admin set-initial-password to set password
- setting dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
- deleting the auth file from dbms folder

**nothing worked**

also, The DBMS directory is empty

[image: The dbms directory is empty]

so I am assuming I have created an instance yet. I couldn't find any article on how to create an enterprise neo4j instance in ubuntu

Comment: If you installed neo4j on ubuntu with apt, it is by default running with user and group neo4j:neo4j. I can see in your screenshot that you are running as root, maybe the permissions on the file system is incorrect.

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: how can I check the permissions of the file system for neo4j

Comment: if you are using a volume for "neo4j/data"  when you run docker that will somehow reset password configuration of db and will ask you to set initial password again